# Inequality involving power to fractional part of integer multiples of logarithm of integer to coprime base.

Tags: inequality, logarithms, ergodic-theory, fractional-part, coprime

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, let $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the *fractional part* of $x$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that

$2^{\{k \log_2(3)\}} < \dfrac{2}{1 + 2^{-k}}$

for $k > 1$.

This inequality seems very true, as in there should be a much tighter bound. It has something to do with the properties of $\log_2(3)$, probably the fact that $2$ and $3$ are coprime integers. It is closely related to the ergodic circle rotation with $\alpha = \log_2(3) \pmod{1}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It seems doable to use the equality

$$k \log_2(3/2) = \dfrac{2k}{\log(2)} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1) \cdot 5^{2n-1}}$$

For any $k$, there is an $m$ such that $k < (2m-1) \cdot 5^{2m-1}$. Then,

$$\{k \log_2(3/2)\} = \left\{ \dfrac{2}{\log(2)} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{k \pmod{(2n-1) \cdot 5^{2n-1}}}{(2n-1) \cdot 5^{2n-1}} + \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{k}{(2n-1) \cdot 5^{2n-1}} \right) \right\}$$

The sum on the right shrinks very fast. We should be able to pick an $m$ so that this contribution is negligible, less than some $\varepsilon$. The sum on the left shouldn't get very large because it gets "all mixed up." There is some value of $2 \leq k \leq (2m-3)\cdot 5^{2m-3}$ that maximizes it with a sum no greater than $1 - [(2m-3)\cdot 5^{2m-3}]^{-1}$.

So, we just need to show that the sum on the right shrinks fast enough so that we can pick an $m$ small enough so that

$$\log_2(1 + 2^{-k}) < [(2m-3)\cdot 5^{2m-3}]^{-1} - \varepsilon$$

Then, we would have

$$\{k \log_2(3)\} < 1 - \log_2(1 + 2^{-k})$$

as desired. This seems very possible because $m$ should grow exponentially slower than $k$. At least, that's the idea I've got so far.

Edit: I forgot about the $1/\log 2$ term, which completely throws off this entire argument :/

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Waring's problem? That problem can also be stated in terms of an inequality involving powers of 2 and 3.

Comment: I looked at Waring's problem, but I don't see a connection yet.

Comment: Part of Waring's problem comes down to whether there is any positive integer $k$ such that $2^k\{(3/2)^k\}+[(3/2)^k]>2^k$.